# How do you change makefile variables file extension?

Tags: variables, makefile, file-extension

For example, I have a variable that holds a list of dependencies

```
BOARDS:=lance.mcm light.mcm sac.mcm
```

I need another variable named NET such that

```
NET:=lance.net light.net sac.net
```

It should be set such that when I change the BOARDS variable, NET should change as well. 
For example, if I add a new zor.mcm into the BOARDS variable, it should automatically add zor.net into the NET variable.

Comment: Superset: multiple extensions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069457/how-to-change-the-extension-of-each-file-in-a-list-with-multiple-extensions-in-g

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to use this syntax:

```
NET:=$(BOARDS:.mcm=.net)
```

This will look at BOARDS and change the .mcm into .net

Comment: A little more explanation at [How to change the extension of each file in a list with multiple extensions in GNU make?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12071918/1730674)

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative:

```
BOARDS:=lance.mcm light.mcm sac.mcm
NET:= $(addsuffix .net, $(basename $(BOARDS)))
```

This will preserve contents inside the file pathnames should they match pattern

Comment: This is why I posted the question in the first place. This is perfect, thanks!