# How to change the extension of each file in a list with multiple extensions in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a GNU makefile, I am wondering if it is possible, with an file list input, to make a file list output with new extensions.

In input, I get this list:

```
FILES_IN=file1.doc file2.xls
```

And I would like to build this variable in my makefile from **FILES_IN** variable:

```
FILES_OUT=file1.docx file2.xlsx
```

Is it possible ? How ?

It's quite difficult because I have to parse file list, and detect each extension (.doc, .xls) to replace it to correct extension.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Substituting extensions in a list of whitespace-separated file names is a common requirement, and there are built-in features for this. If you want to add an `x` at the end of every name in the list:

```
FILES_OUT = $(FILES_IN:=x)
```

The general form is `$(VARIABLE:OLD_SUFFIX=NEW_SUFFIX)`. This takes the value of `VARIABLE` and replaces `OLD_SUFFIX` at the end of each word that ends with this suffix by `NEW_SUFFIX` (non-matching words are left unchanged). GNU make calls this feature (which exists in every make implementation) [substitution references](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs).

If you just want to change `.doc` into `.docx` and `.xls` into `.xlsx` using this feature, you need to use an intermediate variable.

```
FILES_OUT_1 = $(FILES_IN:.doc=.docx)
FILES_OUT = $(FILES_OUT_1:.xls=.xlsx)
```

You can also use the slightly more general syntax `$(VARIABLE:OLD_PREFIX%OLD_SUFFIX=NEW_PREFIX%NEW_SUFFIX)`. This feature is not unique to GNU make, but it is not as portable as the plain suffix-changing substitution.

There is also a GNU make feature that lets you chain multiple substitutions on the same line: the [`patsubst` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions).

```
FILES_OUT = $(patsubst %.xls,%.xlsx,$(patsubst %.doc,%.docx,$(FILES_IN)))
```

Comment: Or just `FILES_OUT := $(patsubst %,%x,$(FILES_IN))` if the rule really can be made that generic.

Comment: What is the name of this operator? I want check the manuals, but cannot find the proper name.

Comment: @rkioji What operator? I give a link to the GNU make manual for `$(VARIABLE:OLD_SUFFIX=NEW_SUFFIX)`, what else are you refering to?

Comment: @Gilles oh yeah, didn't see the link. I referred to "substitution". Thanks!

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - I understand your explanation that `$(VARIABLE:OLD_SUFFIX=NEW_SUFFIX)` means _take the value of VARIABLE and replace OLD_SUFFIX at the end of each word that ends with this suffix by NEW_SUFFIX_. But I'm not clear how that aligns with the apparent "shortcut" of `FILES_OUT = $(FILES_IN:=x)` -- here it appears that you are not specifying _any_ `OLD_SUFFIX`. Is it implicit that if you do not specify `OLD_SUFFIX`, the behavior is to append `NEW_SUFFIX` to every value in `VARIABLE`? (I did not recognize an answer to my question in the gnu make manual)

Comment: @StoneThrow `$(FILES_IN:=x)` is just an instance of the general rule: for each word in the value of `FILES_IN`, if it ends with the old suffix, then replace by the new suffix, else keep the word unchanged. When the old suffix is empty, “if it sends with the old suffix” is always true, so the rule simplifies to “for each word in the value of `FILES_IN`, append the new suffix”.