# How to substitute the extension for a cmake list of filenames

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am trying to build a c++ library from some `protobuf` definitions using cmake.
I added a custom command to compile the `proto` to c++, but I have some issues with the output part.
I need to specify which are the expected output files after `protoc` does its job. For this I would like to replace in my `PROTO_SOURCE`file glob, the `proto` extension with `.pb.cc` and `.pb.h`

I basically need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069457/how-to-change-the-extension-of-each-file-in-a-list-with-multiple-extensions-in-g), but for cmake.

I am building this command manually because I don't have protobuf cmake support available.

```
project(messages)

set(PROTO_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto_definitions")
file(GLOB PROTO_FILES "${PROTO_PATH}/*.proto")
#set(PROTO_SOURCES ???) # This needs to contain '*.pb.cc' and '*.pb.h'

add_custom_command(COMMAND protoc --cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compiled_proto ${PROTO_FILES}
               WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
               DEPENDS ${PROTO_FILES}
               OUTPUT ${PROTO_SOURCES})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${PROTO_SOURCES})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [string(REGEX REPLACE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/string.html#regex-replace) function:

```
# Replace .proto -> .pb.cc
string(REGEX REPLACE "[.]proto$" ".pb.cc" OUTPUT_SOURCES ${PROTO_FILES})
# Replace .proto -> .pb.h
string(REGEX REPLACE "[.]proto$" ".pb.h" OUTPUT_HEADERS ${PROTO_FILES})

add_custom_command(COMMAND protoc <...>
   OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_SOURCES} ${OUTPUT_HEADERS})
```

Comment: yeah, this was the backup plan, I was thinking that there must be a shorter syntax similar to make for this

Comment: PROTO_FILES is a list and when I print it with MESSAGE, I get a continuous string without any separation between the items in the list, so the REPLACE just replaces the last item extension. I ended up using a FOREACH with REPLACE for each item and appending to a new list the results. Now I have different issue but I will ask a separate question for it.

Comment: "PROTO_FILES is a list and when I print it with MESSAGE, I get a continuous string without any separation between the items in the list" - This is correct behavior. For view the separator in `message()` call, wrap the list into **double quotes**. But do not do that in other cases: double quotes makes the list to be a **single value**. The function `string(REGEX REPLACE)` correctly works with lists, when they are passed correctly (**without** double quotes).

Comment: I get the exact same behavior as @codentary & @tjysdsg. This solution results in all the values in `${PROTO_FILES}` being concatenated together **before** substitution is performed (and no quotes are used!). As such, the result is a single concatenated string with only the last file getting replaced. [The documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-replace) supports this as it says "All <input> arguments are concatenated before matching."

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, as the first few elements in the list weren't properly substituted.

So I loop over the list, replace them one by one, and append each one to a list:

```
foreach (CXX_SRC ${LIST_OF_CXX})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "[.]cpp$" ".o" OBJ ${CXX_SRC})
    set(OBJ_FILES ${OBJ_FILES} ${OBJ})
endforeach ()
message(STATUS "Object files compiled from *.cpp: ${OBJ_FILES}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer concatenated all the list entries first, and just replaced the extension on the last one (as others noted). Using the [`TRANSFORM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/list.html#transform) list operation worked to transform the list in-place and replace the file extensions on all entries

```
file(GLOB MY_LIST *.foo)

# transforms MY_LIST=["a.foo", "b.foo"] to MY_LIST=["a.bar", "b.bar"]
list(TRANSFORM MY_LIST REPLACE "[.]foo$" ".bar")
```